# Enable grouping in ListView - Invalid Handle?

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, grouping, common-controls

I do not understand the following situation:

```
    HWND hListView = CreateWindowEx( 0, WC_LISTVIEW, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
                                   LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS, 0,
                                   0, rcl.right - rcl.left, rcl.bottom - rcl.top,
                               hMain,( HMENU ) 1000, inst, NULL);
    int error = GetLastError();//error=0;
    //ListView is displayed correctly
    //Some Code for columns
    //Now trying to enable grouping via SendMessage or following macro returns error:6?
    //What the...
    ListView_EnableGroupView(hListView, TRUE);
    error = GetLastError();//error=6;ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE
    //Some Code for Items
```

So what am i missing ;D ? It's hilarious to get this error while the handle is right there above, working for other things (columns, rows/items)

Edit_1 - 7:27(GMT):
Yep, its always error 6 whenever  its placed after creating columns/items/groups and all kinds of combinations, here is the code:

```
    //Groups - Send-Recv
LVGROUP lvg;
lvg.cbSize = sizeof(LVGROUP);
lvg.mask = LVGF_HEADER | LVGF_GROUPID;

lvg.pszHeader = L"Gr1";
lvg.iGroupId = 1;
ListView_InsertGroup( hListView, - 1, & lvg );
//MessageBoxA(NULL, i2s(GetLastError()).c_str(), "ERROR2", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
lvg.pszHeader = L"Gr2";
lvg.iGroupId = 2;
ListView_InsertGroup( hListView, - 1, & lvg );
    //Enable
ListView_EnableGroupView(hListView, TRUE);
//error 6
```

Comment: Have you actually created any groups? I don't think you can turn group view on until you have added groups to the listview.

Comment: Edited my question. And the answer is "yes, sir".

Answer (score 3):

Only *ever* call GetLastError() when you got a failure return code from the Windows api function **and** the documentation tells you that the api function sets the last error.

Neither is the case here for your usage of ListView_EnableGroupView().

Comment: Agreed. `ListView_EnableGroupView()` returns its own error code directly if it fails, it does not use `GetLastError()`.